# Use for each in xslt

Tags: xslt

Input :

```
<lq>
   <ol class="- topic/ol ">
     <li>Text 1
       <ol class="- topic/ol ">
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
       </ol>
     </li>
     <li>Text 4</li>
     <li>Text 5</li>
   </ol>
</lq>
```

Out should be :

```
<node>
  <p type="extract_number_1">Text 1</p>
  <p type="extract_number_2">Text 2</p>
  <p type="extract_number_2">Text 3</p>
  <p type="extract_number_1">Text 4</p>
  <p type="extract_number_1">Text 5</p>
</node>
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="lq/ol">
    <xsl:for-each select="li">
        <p type="extract_number_{position()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I have mentioned above my `Input` `Output should be` and `Tried code`. Here `<p>` `@type` should be `<li>` position.

As my tried code I am not getting expected output. I am using XSLT 2.0. How can I solve this. Thank you.

Comment: `select="li"` should go all the way down: `select=".//li"` (just a guess, I have no toolset here)

Comment: Where does the number in the `type` attribute come from? It doesn't seem to be a position at all. Do you look for the nesting level?

Comment: @MartinHonnen it is the position of `li`. `Text 1` belongs to level 1 `li`. `Text 2` and `Text 3` inside of level 1 `li`. Then they are `2nd` level.

Comment: @ThomasWeller. I used it. but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the number in the `type` attribute to show the nesting level then use e.g.

```
    <xsl:template match="lq/ol">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//li"/>
    </xsl:template>  

   <xsl:template match="lq/ol//li">
        <p type="extract_number_{count(ancestor::ol)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </p>
   </xsl:template>
```